# spring-webmvc/hibernate-validator not invalidating bad data during test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm reading **Spring In Action**, and I'm working through the example *spittr* web application for `spring-mvc`. The book discusses using `javax.annotation.constraints` to describe valid data, e.g.

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
public class Spitter {
   @NotNull
   @Size(min=5, max=16)
   private String username;
   //...
}
```

Then, it says, you can apply validation to a method using the `@Valid` decorator for arguments, e.g.

```java
import        javax.validation.Valid;
import        org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import        org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/spitter"})
public class SpitterController {
  @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=POST)
  public String processRegistration(@Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
      return "registerForm";
    }
    return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUsername();
  }
  //...
}
```

To check my understanding of the material, I tried writing some tests to see the method react to invalid data:

```java
import        org.junit.Test;
import        org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*;
public class SpitterControllerTest {
  @Test
  public void shouldNotProcessEmptyRegistration() throws Exception {
    standaloneSetup(new SpitterController())
      .build()
      .perform(post("/spitter/register"))
      .andExpect(view().name("registerForm"));
  }
  @Test
  public void shouldNotProcessInvalidRegistration() throws Exception {
    standaloneSetup(new SpitterController())
      .build()
      .perform(post("/spitter/register").param("username", "x"))
      .andExpect(view().name("registerForm"));
  }
  //...
}
```

And I was surprised when the tests failed

```
shouldNotProcessEmptyRegistration(spittr.web.SpitterControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.013 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: View name expected:<registerForm> but was:<redirect:/spitter/null>
shouldNotProcessInvalidRegistration(spittr.web.SpitterControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.013 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: View name expected:<registerForm> but was:<redirect:/spitter/x>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I know what happens at test time has a good deal to do with what's on the classpath:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.13.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I think it's likely that I'm missing some dependency the book didn't bother to mention, but at this point I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Most of what I've been able to find by googling discusses spring-boot, which I'm trying to put off for now; I'd like to understand spring first before I start trying to understand what spring-boot brings to the table (but **Spring Boot In Action** is next on my reading list).

What do I need to do to fix my code so that the controller successfully detects the invalid data when testing?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in your code your are requiring the username of a spitter to not be null, however that does not mean that the entire object cant be null. In your current setup the request body is optional. You could try:

`public String processRegistration(@RequestBody @Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors)`

By default `@RequestBody` makes the body required.

Comment: `spitter` isn't `null` during this test, if it were `spitter.getUsername()` would throw `NullPointerException` instead of returning `null`.  I tried adding the `@RequestBody` decorator as you indicated, but that just made the test fail with `java.lang.AssertionError` even when given valid data.

Comment: My bad then, although I still dont see where the request body in your test is coming from. the test code you provide make it look like an empty post request.

Comment: I'll add another test to show it fails for non-null but invalid usernames too